# Kendo mobile Viemodel: using "this" inside the Viewmodel

Tags: javascript, html, viewmodel, kendo-mobile

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="bills" data-role="view" data-model="Bills" data-init="Bills.init" data-layout="default">        
    <h1 data-bind="text:name">Text</h1>
</div>
```

and the ViewModel for this is:

```
var Bills = kendo.observable({
    name: "John Doe",
    init: function() {
        this.doSomething();
    },

    doSomething: function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
});
```

Both codeparts with "this" are not working. "this.doSomething" produces the error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'doSomething'
```

Why is it not possible to use "this" in such a ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

"this" in your context is the same as $('#bills'). It's your div view. I think you want to call Bills.doSomething(); or you can call this.model.doSomething();

I can't articulate why that is but that's what is going on. Good Luck!